# How to display specific user data from Firebase into a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on my first firebase android application and its almost done but I'm stuck in retriving the data from data base, Adding and updating of data is working fine.
In my viewInformation layout it is not entering into forloop of showData method (checked using log cat)
I want to display the data to the specific user who is logged in. (Only his/her data will be displayed)

Here is my Firebase DB structure:
[image: my Firebase DB structure]

**Display Information Code:**

```
public class ViewInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ViewInformation";
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
String userID;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_information);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); //get current user
    userID = user.getUid(); //get userID of current user

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null ...launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewInformation.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };


      mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              showData(dataSnapshot);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          }

      });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        userInformation uInfo = new userInformation();
        uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).child("Name").getValue(userInformation.class).getName());
        uInfo.setGender(ds.child(userID).child("Gender").getValue(userInformation.class).getGender());
        uInfo.setMobile_Number(ds.child(userID).child("Mobile_Number").getValue(userInformation.class).getMobile_Number());
        uInfo.setAddress(ds.child(userID).child("Address").getValue(userInformation.class).getAddress());

        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Name: " + uInfo.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Gender: " + uInfo.getGender());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mobile_Number: " + uInfo.getMobile_Number());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Address: " + uInfo.getAddress());

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(uInfo.getName());
        array.add(uInfo.getGender());
        array.add(uInfo.getMobile_Number());
        array.add(uInfo.getAddress());
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
}
```

**Getter/Setter methods: (userInformation.java)**

```
package com.scoratech.scoraxchange;
public class userInformation {

private String Name;
private String Gender;
private String Mobile_Number;
private String Address;

 public userInformation(){
 }

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return Gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.Gender = gender;
}

public String getMobile_Number() {
    return Mobile_Number;
}

public void setMobile_Number(String mobile_Number) {
    this.Mobile_Number = mobile_Number;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.Address = address;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retrieving a non-existent node in `mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("list-abc05")`. The root of your project's database is unnamed, so:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
```

In addition, I'd recommend only attaching the listener once the user has been authenticated (so from within `onAuthStateChanged`). That way you already know the UID of the user, so can attach directly to their node (instead of retrieving the data for all users):

```
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();     
authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ViewInformation.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        else {
            userID = user.getUid();
            mRef.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showData(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

private void showData(DataSnapshot ds) {

    userInformation uInfo = new userInformation();
    uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).child("Name").getValue(userInformation.class).getName());
    uInfo.setGender(ds.child(userID).child("Gender").getValue(userInformation.class).getGender());
    uInfo.setMobile_Number(ds.child(userID).child("Mobile_Number").getValue(userInformation.class).getMobile_Number());
    uInfo.setAddress(ds.child(userID).child("Address").getValue(userInformation.class).getAddress());

    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Name: " + uInfo.getName());
    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Gender: " + uInfo.getGender());
    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mobile_Number: " + uInfo.getMobile_Number());
    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Address: " + uInfo.getAddress());

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add(uInfo.getName());
    array.add(uInfo.getGender());
    array.add(uInfo.getMobile_Number());
    array.add(uInfo.getAddress());
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. About the DB reference i was trying to give specific root node, that i changed later. I tried your code but its not working and the variable `ds` you are not initializing it in for loop.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't rename the argument. Did so now.

Comment: I think the error is in showData method, i want to access root nodes child(which is a unique ID for every user) but my code is accessing child of root nodes child.